# TestStack.White.Uia3 WindowsFramework.InternetExplorer Texbox not found

Tags: unit-testing, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests, browser-automation, white-framework

We are writing test cases for WPF application. Inside WPF application we are opening a web browser window (internet explorer) and trying to find input element.

We installed 'TestStack.White.Uia3.0.13.3' package for finding elements inside the browser.

We able to find button element which is rendered inside HTML page like `<button class="accbtn" id="SignIn">User SignIn</button>`

to find this element we written code like `window.Get<Button>(SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("SignIn").AndOfFramework(WindowsFramework.InternetExplorer));`

In a similar way we are trying to find textbox. Which is rendered on html page like `<input id="userid" type="email" name="login" value="">`

to find this element we written code like `var textbox = window.Get<TextBox>(SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("userid").AndOfFramework(WindowsFramework.InternetExplorer))`

But it is not finding element from the page. I see difference like the rendered html have type='email' instead of type='text' but I thought it should find.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue using AutomationElement of a window. There is a like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement.findfirst(v=vs.110).aspx which describes how to get automationelement.

After I got automationelement followed valuepattern to insert value into textbox